# Darksiders 3 multiple weapons +11?

Tags: darksiders-3

With the release of "The Crucible" DLC, it is possible to upgrade at least one weapon to +11 after beating the crucible stage 1-101 in a go. This will award upgrade material to upgrade a weapon to +11.

**The question is, is it possible to obtain the material multiple times, by defeating all stages over and over and thus upgrading all weapons to +11 or ist a one time only drop?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though not an direct answer to the question, the answer with the release of the "Keepers of The Void" DLC is, that it is possible to buy the "Wicked Adamantite" for 50k souls, which is used to upgrade weapons to +13.

As this is possible now, I'd assume, that the "Wicked Adamantite" would drop multiple times.